# Generate multivariate monomials with constraints

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, expression-construction

I'm trying to generate multivariate monomials in variables $p_1, \ldots, p_n$. Each monomial has either $p_i$ as a factor, otherwise $(1-p_i)$. I need to generate all monomials which have exactly $k$ variables in the $p_i$ form.

(Essentially there are $n$ coin tosses, the coins having probabilities $p_i$, and I want all monomials corresponding to the probabilities of different ways of getting exactly $k$ heads.)

I tried generating subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ of size $k$ and manipulating the resulting lists into monomials, but I'm too inexperienced with Mathematica.

eg. if $n=3$ and $k=1$, the list of monomials are
$$\{p_1(1-p_2)(1-p_3), (1-p_1)p_2(1-p_3), (1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_3\}$$

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[n_, i_] := Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[i, {n}, {0, 1}]
f2[n_, i_] := Module[{pr = Array[Subscript[p, #]&, n]}, 
  Times @@ (pr^# (1 - pr)^(1 - #)) & /@ f1[n, i][[1]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
f2[3, 1] // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{p_1 \left(1-p_2\right) \left(1-p_3\right),\left(1-p_1\right) p_2
>    \left(1-p_3\right),\left(1-p_1\right) \left(1-p_2\right) p_3\right\}$

```
f2[4, 2] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  p_1 p_2 \left(1-p_3\right) \left(1-p_4\right) \\
>  p_1 \left(1-p_2\right) p_3 \left(1-p_4\right) \\
>  p_1 \left(1-p_2\right) \left(1-p_3\right) p_4 \\
>  \left(1-p_1\right) p_2 p_3 \left(1-p_4\right) \\
>  \left(1-p_1\right) p_2 \left(1-p_3\right) p_4 \\
>  \left(1-p_1\right) \left(1-p_2\right) p_3 p_4 \\
> \end{array}$

Alternatively, you can use the `PDF` of the joint distribution of `n` independent Bernoulli random variables:

```
ClearAll[f3]
f3[n_, i_] := Module[{dist = ProductDistribution @@ 
     Array[BernoulliDistribution @ Subscript[p, #] &, n]},
  PDF[dist, #] & /@ First[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[i, {n}, {0, 1}]]]

f3[3, 1] == f2[3, 1]
```

> True

```
f3[5, 3] == f2[5, 3]
```

> True